# Where To Ask - Informal Question About A Database

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I know about the DBA Stack Exchange, but I want to know if my specific question is too simple to ask there. I want to know how to deal with a record storing an ID pointing to a list of items (that varies widely in size). More specifically I want to know what that list of items should be (e.g., a massive record in a table, a table itself, or something I'm unaware of).

Also, I wish I could do more research on this before I even post a question anywhere, but none of my searches give any meaningful results. My assumptions are that there is a term that describes this that I don't know, or that I'm just approaching the problem the wrong way.

Comment: For starters try searching on the buzzphrase "first normal form"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBA Stack Exchange's [Asking](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page clearly states that questions about "Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity" are on-topic, so your question should be OK there. Note, however, that this is a very common issue in database design, and unless you have some interesting details about your specific usecase, it's quite possible that this question would be closed as a duplicate of some canonical question.

Also, depending on how much your question has to do with programming against such a database, it may also be on-topic on Stack Overflow, although YMMV.

Finally, I suggest you read up about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to get some theoretical background that will help you flesh out your question.